# Deactivate Huge Strings in Delphi 2010

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-2010

I'm new in Delphi and I was migrating a very old Delphi project to Embarcadero RAD Studio 2010. I found a problem using strings. Here is the code:

```
ProgramaResultadosType = record
    Version: string;
    TituloPrincipal   : string;
    BloquesResultados : VectorBloquesResultadosType;
end;

FileOfProgramaResultadosType  = file of ProgramaResultadosType;
```

And the error...

> "E2155 Type '%s' needs finalization - not allowed in file type"

I know it's a well-known error for many delphi developers when you don't specify the string size.

Basically I would like to deactivate Huge strings directive like older versions of RAD Studio, but I can't find out in the 2010 version.

Comment: Are you tried using the embarcadero advice [E2155: Type '%s' needs finalization - not allowed in file type (Delphi)](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/cm_finit_in_file_xml.html) and use an array of char instead?

Comment: D2010 can't "deactivate" huge string any longer because the string type became Unicode. Unicode support is deeply embedded, thereby it can't switch back to any old ANSI string type.
You should start to remove all "file" types. They are really obsolete.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use instead:

```
ProgramaResultadosType = record
    Version: shortstring;
    TituloPrincipal   : shortstring;
    BloquesResultados : VectorBloquesResultadosType;
end;
```

But be aware that:

- Almost every call to a RTL function will first make an invisible conversion to the new `string` type: you should better use another explicit `string` variable just after having read the `shortstring` content;
- In newer version of Delphi (starting with Delphi 2009), `string` is an Unicode string: so you may lose some data when writing into a `shortstring` (which is an Ansi string) from an `UnicodeString`;
- Perhaps adding `ProgramaResultadosType = packed record` could be necessary if your application is very very old (default alignment changed around Delphi 4, AFAIR).

So you may have to:

- Read the existing content using structures like the above;
- Write using a new paradigm, Unicode ready (e.g. an embedded DB like Midas, SQLite3 or any other).

Worth reading when converting an existing application to newer Unicode version of Delphi:

- [Series of articles](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/understanding-unicode-support-in-delphi.htm);
- [Presentation by Marco](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/images/38980/Delphi_and_Unicode.pdf);
- [Delphi Unicode Migration for Mere Mortals: Stories and Advice from the Front Lines](http://www.embarcadero.com/images/dm/technical-papers/delphi-unicode-migration.pdf).

Comment: @David How do you know I've a loose tooth? Thanks for the edit - I always did this mistake, without knowing it... :)

Comment: there is a mnemonic: choose has 2 "o" that you can *choose* from, but lose has only 1 because if you *lose* 1 you only have 1 left.